# Error in simultaneous request to the same url using axios

Tags: node.js, express, request, axios

Hello I am trying to consume an external api from a nodejs + express backend and I cannot make a multiple request to the same url but with different parameters using axios since it returns error 500 and the message "Sorry. We have detected that there are simultaneous requests." What and tried according to the documentation is the following but it does not work:

```
await axios.all([
  axios.get(url1, { params: params_1}),
  axios.get(url1, { params: params_2})
]).then(axios.spread((res1, res2) => {
      console.log(res1)
      console.log(res2)
}));
```

I also tried using promises but it doesn't work either, getting the same error.

```
 await Promise.all([     
     axios.get(url1, { params: params_1 }),      
     axios.get(url1, { params: params_2 })
 ]).then(([res1,res2])=>{
     console.log(res1),
     console.log(res2)
 })
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?, thanks.

Comment: Since you're receiving a 500 from the server, it seems like you may be hitting a limitation of the API. If possible for your use case, I'd make the calls separately (and probably use `async`/`await` for code readability). If they succeed separately, then you've found your issue.

Comment: Apparently the API you are consuming won't allow multiple simultaneous requests. The API is probably doing this for a good reason (resource management for example) so I wouldn't try to get around it. If this is something you really need to do for some reason I would suggest contacting whoever operates that API.